# How to delete Image from NSMutableArray and UI in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to delete image from mutable array and also from UIImage.

To add an image in array my code is like this:

In `connectionDidFinishLoading`

```
   imageArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i<idarray.count; i++) {
        [imageArray addObject:[UIImage new]];
    }   

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    CGSize newSizeClient=CGSizeMake(200,200); // I am giving resolution 50*50 , you can change your need
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSizeClient);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSizeClient.width, newSizeClient.height)];
    UIImage* newImageClient = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    captureimg.image = newImageClient;
    
    [imageArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:captureimg.image];
    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [Audittable reloadData];
    });
    
    NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation((newImageClient), 0.5)];
    OCSSignString = [imgData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
    
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30,40,40)];
    UIImage *wonImage = captureimg.image;
    imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeCenter;
    [imageView setImage:wonImage];
}
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.CaptureImage.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

When deleting I am using code like this

```
[imageArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
```

But it crashes. I am using a custom TableView.

How can I remove image from mutable array?

More code:

`CellForrowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.btnRemove.tag=indexPath.row;
 [cell.btnRemove addTarget:self action:@selector(btnRemoveClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

On Button Click

```
-(void)btnRemoveClick:(UIButton *)sender
{
    AuditNextTableViewCell *cell = sender.superview.superview;
    // NSLog(@"%@",cell.actuallbl.text);
    
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [Audittable indexPathForCell:cell];
    CurrentIndexPath=indexPath.row;
    
    UIAlertView *Alertview =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!" message:@"Are You Sure you want to delete Image" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
    CheckStringShow=@"7";
    [Alertview show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
            [imageArray removeObjectAtIndex:CurrentIndexPath];
            [Audittable reloadData];
}
```

It is removing current object only means last added object in array. I want to remove image at current index.

Comment: What is referencing to index variable at removing it from array? indexPath.row?

Comment: can u show you are  'numberOfRowsInSection' and cellForRowAtIndexPath' code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please confirm below:

1. Object must be present in your `imageArray`  of that `index`.
2. Use your code `[imageArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];` outside the
   tableview datasource method.

and last

3. Reload UITableView `[tableView reloadData]` after remove object from array.

Comment: it is getting cash.

Comment: Could you please edit your question in brief? So that I can see in which method your removing object from array.

Answer (score 1):

After removing the image from the mutable array you have to reload the data of the table view. ;)